# Return data from a screen on Flutter, without using Navigator.pop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I have a DetailPage that must return something to the code that called it. The documentation [Return data from a screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data) explains that you must call `Navigator.pop(context, whateverYouMustReturn)` on some button.

So far so good, but what happens if the user clicks on the *back* button on the `AppBar` instead??  How do I return something then??

PS I'm using Navigator 1.0, btw

Comment: So how about restricting the user from going back to the previous screen?

Comment: You can easily remove the back button from the Appbar and also the system navigation bar can be controlled by WillPopScope widget above scaffold in widget tree.

Comment: Could you turn this into a answer please? I'll accept it if there's no other way around it.

Comment: Hey! I have answered it. Please let me know whether it's working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide your own leading widget and override the callback.

```dart
      AppBar(
        leading: BackButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(myData);
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Container(), //Make leading an empty container to hide the default back button 
  ),
  body: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      Navigator.pop(context); //This method returns future boolean, based on your condition you can either 
      return true; //allow you to go back or you can show a toast and restrict in this page
    },
    child: Container(), //Your details page widget instead of container
  ),
);
}
```